# Error en calidad de canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Por qué la calidad de letra del filltext se ve así?***

> Código:

```
/* Área de programación */ 

$(function(){
 var w = window;
    var d = document;
    var dW = d.body.clientWidth;
    var dH = d.body.clientHeight;
    console.log(dW);
 var c = d.getElementById("can");   
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    /* Dibujando el fondo */
ctx.fillStyle = "#111111";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,dW,dH); 
    /* Dibujando el título */

    ctx.font = "7px monospace";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillText("Programando en Cosmos Theories !",20,50);   
    ctx.fill();


});




/* Fin */
```

Answer (score 0):

la calidad de visualización se debe a que canvas maneja pixeles hay que tener siempre cuidado con la dimensiones.
Por ejemplo si ajustaste el tamaño del canvas con css.

Este es resultado que obtuve yo usando tú ejemplo y en html solo incluí la etiqueta canvas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]